# Why does apache keep changing my host name?

Tags: django, reverse-proxy

So I have a Django application server all set up using Apache and uWSGI and a proxy system. One small problem...Something keeps changing my hostname!!!

It almost resembles a rewrite rule but I searched my httpd.conf and couldn't find any that fits the bill. Whenever I send an HTTP URL:

```
http://www.example.com/polls
```

Django receives this url from the proxy:

```
http://www.example.com/kpolls
```

It's really annoying! something keeps adding that damn `k` to my hostname and I have no idea what! Please help!

## Some extra info:

So my proxy so far is pretty simple:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152/var/run/app_name.sock"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152/var/run/app_name.sock"
```

(tried `localhost` and `www.example.com` just to be sure. no effect so hostname is resolving correctly.)

Seems to me that the proxy is altering it before handing the request off to Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out FINALLY!

Turns out it was my use of UNIX socket notation in the proxy and in the .ini config file. In a nutshell, I had the following:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152/var/run/app_name.sock"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152/var/run/app_name.sock"
```

And I needed to get rid of some of it to look like this:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:49152"
```

because I was using the `uwsgi` protocol through my apache `mod_proxy_uwsgi` install which automaticaly links it up to the running uWSGI instance but the full request/path was mapping to a `.sock` file commonly used in UNIX socket methods (Oh, turns out my apache version cant handle `unix://` requests yet). Basically, I was using some weird hybrid of a UNIX socket and uWSGI proxy protocol which was confusing the server and adding the erroneous letter to every `GET` request